# Display the order total and the number of products sold for order number

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm hoping someone might be able to help guide me in the right direction? I'm trying to write a query where the report will display the order total and number of products sold for that order number, I pasted what I have and hopefully I am headed on the right path. Thanks in advance!

```
select distinct od.OrderID, AVG( od.unitprice * od.quantity / od.Discount) 'try',
od.ProductID
from OrderDetails od
where od.OrderID = 10251
group by od.orderid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> display the order total and number of products sold for that order number

This should do it:

```
SELECY OrderID, -- Order Id
       count(*) as items, -- number of products
       SUM(unitprice * quantity / Discount) as total -- order total
FROM OrderDetails
WHERE OrderID = 10251
GROUP BY OrderID
```

Comment: appreciate the help @gab